# Change the Normal Style

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to programmatically alter the main built-in fonts in a Word document. At present, I've been updating them from another template, but I see a risk if the other template is not present when deployed, so I'd like to specify them in code alone.

```
     ActiveDocument.Styles.Add Name:="Normal", Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph
     ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").AutomaticallyUpdate = True
     With ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").font
         .Name = "3Dumb"                     ' random font to see it works
         .Size = 10
         .Bold = True
         .Italic = True
         .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
         .UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic       'etc...
```

Obviously, VBA complains because that is a built-in style. However, there doesn't seem to be a Styles.Edit Method.

Does anyone know of a solution to redefine built in styles in Word?

MTIA

Fr. S

Comment: If you are using Word 2007 or later using code to edit the Normal style will result in it no longer matching the document defaults (*set from the Set Defaults tab of the Manage Styles dialog accessed via the button at the bottom of the Styles Pane*). This will result in Table Styles not working correctly. The document defaults cannot be changed using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the style but reference it:

```vb
Sub alterStyles()

Dim sty As Style
Set sty = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal)

With sty.Font
    .Name = "3Dumb"
End With

         
End Sub
```

Use the `wdBuiltInStyle`-constants to access the styles - as their names are not the same over different languages.

But usually it is the use case of templates to provide the correct styles ... not a macro that changes them...